# ephem: how to get tilt angle of Earth?

Tags: astronomy, pyephem

I am using python's package ephem.

I can not locate function to get tilt angle between ecliptic plane and equatorial plane.

Hope some one can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Since 0° right ascension is defined as the point where the equatorial and ecliptic planes cross, they are farthest apart at 90° right ascension, where their distance from each other is the same as the Earth’s tilt on its axis:

```
from ephem import Equatorial, Ecliptic
p = Equatorial('90', '0', epoch='2000')
print Ecliptic(p).lat
```

The result is the Earth’s axial tilt at the beginning of the year 2000:

```
23:26:21.4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.

Hon-Jang

Answer (score -1):

Bit of Googling might give you your answer:

- [Measure the tilt of the Earth today!](http://scienceblogs.com/startswithabang/2010/06/21/measure-the-tilt-of-the-earth)
- [Measure the Tilt of the Earth on the Solstice!](http://scienceblogs.com/startswithabang/2012/06/19/measure-the-tilt-of-the-earth-on-the-solstice-this-wednesday)
- [Declination Angle](http://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/properties-of-sunlight/declination-angle)

Comment: Thanks. But what I want is:    Use function in pyephem to get tilt angle.

Comment: Those links I gave you should give enough to be able to calculate it yourself using a mixture of PyEphem and Python...or so I thought if I understand your question.  I wanted to calculate the bright limb angle of the moon for a project I did and I used PyEphem for the location of the body (moon and earth) and Python, plus references to astronomical books!